# Dialogflow - a very basic question about fulfilment intent not showing using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have spent one hour searching so I gave up. This question is a little silly.

My intent is to have a specific reply based on parameter received. For example, if a user says “I’m angry because of my boss” then the reply will be “boss is the worst” but if it’s about “wife” then it will say “remember that you promise to love her forever, your mistake”

Anyway, based on my reading I should be using app.intent but I’m not sure how to use it yet

My current question is, this fulfilment is returning empty

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {
  dialogflow
} = require('actions-on-google');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const app = dialogflow();
 
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements
 
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  
function angerEmotionCapture(agent) {
  let conv = agent.conv();
  conv.ask('Hello from the Actions on Google client library!');
  agent.add(conv);
  }
  
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('angerEmotionCapture', angerEmotionCapture);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow ... I couldn't follow your logic/flow of code, so instead, here is a recipe to build a fulfillment handler.  See if you can walk through this recipe and get a sample fulfillment running.  Hopefully you can get that going which will loop back to what you need to your own project

https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/quick/fulfillment

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm super new to this. I think I mess up, I was mainly using the documentation from here https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/reference/nodejsv2/overview - That's probably why it doesn't make sense